# How to fix a linear gradient from repeating

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have been trying to stop my linear gradient from repeating itself, my code seems right but i'm missing something. For some reason it keeps repeating itself even with the no-repeat tag. I appreciate you taking a look!

I have tried to add the html tag to the css, added background-size:cover,...

```css
body,
html {
  font-size: 95%;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, #1C1C1C 10%, #494949 360%), no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
  font-size: 95%;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, #1C1C1C 10%, #494949 360%) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>test</h1>
</body>
```

There was extra `,` right before `no-repeat` remove the `,` and try now.

```
body ,html{
        font-size: 95%;
        text-align: center;
        background: linear-gradient(360deg, #1C1C1C 10%, #494949 360%) no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;

    }
```

Comment: alright that did something, it stopped repeating but half my screen is white now. Anyway to fix this? (sorry for being such a rookie)

Comment: @Jelly1738 check the duplicate, you need `height:100%` on html

Comment: yeah that fixed it! thank you guys so much!